# Have every item at exact same position on resize

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have following design which looks like the left version in 1920x1080. When I resize the window, I want the design to look exactly like the "huge" version. So, not just a background that scales (with "cover") and images that scale when there is no more room ("width: 100%") but that every item scales immediately and the design always looks the "same".

Main thing/reason is that blue background. It has transparent edges around yellow items. Now when I resize, the items don't always fall into the "same place", therefore the transparent "slots" don't match anymore.

Also now when I resize window, parts of the yellow "bar" moves into two rows etc. Please note, that by resize I just mean a resize with same aspect ratio (1920x1080 -> 1024x576 etc).

[image: example]

Here is it in action: https://codepen.io/sigug/full/wjeavE/

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 background: #fd1dfa;

}

@keyframes move_header {
    from { top: -200px; }
    to { top: 0px; }
}

@keyframes move_footer {
    from { bottom: -200px; }
    to { bottom: 0px; }
}

#header {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 200px;

 background: url(https://preview.ibb.co/b3u2b7/background_header.png) repeat-x center top, linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0));
 background-size: cover;

 animation-name: move_header;
    animation-duration: 1.8s;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 200px;

 background: url(https://preview.ibb.co/i6jPpS/background_footer.png) repeat-x center bottom, linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
 background-size: cover;

 animation-name: move_footer;
    animation-duration: 2s;
 text-align: center;
}



img { width: 100%;
 height: auto;}

#header #bar {
 position: relative;
 top: 115px;
}

#footer #bar {
 position: relative;
 top: 15px;
}

#header #line_left {
 display: inline-block;

 width: 40%;
 height: 10px;
 background: url(https://image.ibb.co/kgLVUS/header_line_left.png) repeat-x left center;
}

#header #icons {
 display: inline-block;
   margin: auto auto;

 max-width: 200px;
 text-align: center;
}

#header #line_right {
 display: inline-block;

 width: 40%;
 height: 10px;
 background: url(https://image.ibb.co/kgLVUS/header_line_right.png) repeat-x right center;
}


#footer #line_left {
 display: inline-block;

 width: 30%;
 height: 10px;
 background: url(https://image.ibb.co/kgLVUS/footer_line_left.png) repeat-x left center;
}

#footer #icons {
 display: inline-block;
   margin: auto auto;

 max-width: 900px;
 text-align: center;
}

#footer #line_right {
 display: inline-block;

 width: 30%;
 height: 10px;
 background: url(https://image.ibb.co/kgLVUS/footer_line_right.png) repeat-x right center;
}


#footer li, #header li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 opacity: 0.7;
}

#footer li:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}

#footer li .left {
 max-width: 50px;
}

#footer li .space {
 max-width: 20px;
}

#footer li .center {
 max-width: 70px;
}

#footer li .right {
 max-width: 50px;
}

#header li .center {
 max-width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
 <div id="bar">
  <div id="line_left"></div>
  <div id="icons">
   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ewR4pS/icon_temp.png" class="center"></li>
  </div>
  <div id="line_right"></div>
 </div>
</div>


<div id="footer">
 <div id="bar">
  <div id="line_left"></div>
  <div id="icons">
   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ewR4pS/icon_temp.png" class="left"></li>
   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ewR4pS/icon_temp.png" class="left"></li>
   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ewR4pS/icon_temp.png" class="left"></li>
   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ewR4pS/icon_temp.png" class="left"></li>

   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/gocNb7/blank.png" class="space"></li>

   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ewR4pS/icon_temp.png" class="center"></li>
   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ewR4pS/icon_temp.png" class="center"></li>
   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ewR4pS/icon_temp.png" class="center"></li>
   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ewR4pS/icon_temp.png" class="center"></li>

   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/gocNb7/blank.png" class="space"></li>

   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ewR4pS/icon_temp.png" class="right"></li>
   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ewR4pS/icon_temp.png" class="right"></li>
   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ewR4pS/icon_temp.png" class="right"></li>
   <li><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ewR4pS/icon_temp.png" class="right"></li>
  </div>
  <div id="line_right"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked into viewport units?

Comment: Exactly what @sol Said, replace your fixed units with the viewport units, it should resize as the windows gets wider or taller.

Comment: Thank you, I updated: https://codepen.io/sigug/full/ELXRPV/
One of the issues still remain, that items move to the next row when window gets smaller, even though everything is with viewport size?